# "test: argument expected " met when test a file using "-e" option

Tags: testing, ksh

When executing following code segment, error "test: argument expected" always occurs. However, if I change "-e" to "-s", this error will disappear. Is it possible to eliminate this error but keep "-e" unchanged?

```
OAMPROXY_BKOUT_SPF="/var/ap/platform/rccCfgBkup/backout.spf"
if [ -e ${OAMPROXY_BKOUT_SPF} ] && [ "${IS_GENERIC_RETROFIT}" = "no" ]
then
    # Do something here
fi
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's just really weird. What happens if you use `-f`? What version of ksh? What OS?

Comment: I used ksh88 on Red Hat Linux. I have no time to test `-f` yet, since this problem can only be re-produced by executing a very large script (the error won't happen if you execute above ksh command in KSH window directly).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try rewriting the expression as

```
if [[ -e "${OAMPROXY_BKOUT_SPF}" && "${IS_GENERIC_RETROFIT}" = "no" ]]
then
  # do something
fi
```

Also, when I hear 'since this problem can only be re-produced by executing a very large script (the error won't happen if you execute above ksh command in KSH window directly).', my experience says that the error is really above the error that is getting flagged. Most likely a misspelled variable or possibly unmatched brace/bracket or quote.

I bet that when you have time to test with -f, you get the same error.

Let us know how it goes.